# Check if there is hidden div

Tags: jquery

How do check on click if there's at least one div hidden among other div's within #main?

```
$('#main div').click(function(){


});

<div id="main">
    <div style="display:block"></div>
    <div style="display:block"></div>
    <div style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if($("#main div:hidden").length > 0) {
  // atleast 1 div is hidden
}
```

You may want to do `#main > div:hidden` if you only want to check direct descendents.

Answer (score 1):

```
var doesHiddenDivExist = $('#main div:hidden').length > 0;
```